# Unable to capture traffic on proxy port for http url

Tags: http-proxy, zap

I am running a Groovy script to capture traffic over proxy port in OWASP ZAP.

For https site, I am setting the proxy as given below and I can see the traffic in ZAP when I run my script.

```
System.setProperty('https.proxyPort', '8083')
System.setProperty('https.proxyHost', '127.0.0.1')
```

For http site, I am setting the proxy as given below but I can not see the traffic.

```
System.setProperty('http.proxyPort', '8083')
System.setProperty('http.proxyHost', '127.0.0.1')
```

The same settings although work fine when configured on Chrome. I have tried using the IP address instead of 127.0.0.1 but that also did not help. What could be going on wrong here ?

Comment: Try Chrome with `--proxy-bypass-list=<-loopback>` .. https://www.zaproxy.org/docs/desktop/start/proxies/

Comment: Is this groovy within ZAP or external to ZAP?

Comment: External to ZAP